# How route-points <rtept> and track-points <trkpt> can exist in a GPX file together

Tags: xml, gpx

Is it a valid schema to have both route points and track points in a single GPX file representing the same route at the same time? In this format -

```xml
<gpx>
    <rte>
        <rtept lat="13.09993" lon="77.58959">
            <name>Start</name>
            <cmt>Start of route</cmt>
        </rtept>
        <rtept lat="13.10052" lon="77.58847">
            <name>Left</name>
            <cmt>Turn left onto SH 9</cmt>
        </rtept>
    </rte>

    <trk>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="13.09993" lon="77.58959">
                <ele>923.2</ele>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="13.10031" lon="77.58915">
                <ele>924.0</ele>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="13.1006699" lon="77.58872">
                <ele>924.1</ele>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: You could validate against the schema ~ https://www.topografix.com/gpx/1/1/gpx.xsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can co-exist. While they may superficially seem to be similar objects ( ordered collections of points), they are semantically different objects. A route is a set of points which, if followed, lead you to a destination. A track is an ordered history of points of places you've been. The schema allows multiple instances of objects of each type (as well as object types). The fact that two objects (routes or tracks) contain the same sequence of points is irrelevant to the standard. Keep in mind that if you were to create a GPX file with a route and a track containing identical sequences of points, there is nothing in the standard to enforce this consistency into the future.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I never realised until now that route-points are meant for a planned route and track points are meant for done-route. However, its hardly ever used like that. Almost all route planning apps online export the route as track points. I'm actually looking for the best way to embed turn-by-turn instructions in a GPX file. Some apps use route points, some use waypoints. Waypoints doesn't seem to be the logically correct way to add instructions, hence I wondered if I could combine instructions as route points and the route itself as track points. Anyways, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

"*I'm actually looking for the best way to embed turn-by-turn instructions in a GPX file.*"

-Addding turn by turn instructions in the trackpoints of a gpx trackfile.

```
<src>RouteYou</src>
<type>Cycle-short</type>
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="51.040968" lon="3.992143">
        <ele>3.8</ele>
        <time>2020-07-29T18:26:42Z</time>
        <name>Start</name>
        <cmt>Bareldonkdreef</cmt>
        <sym>pass_place</sym>
        <type>Via</type>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="51.042147" lon="3.990702">
        <ele>4.8</ele>
        <time>2020-07-29T18:27:09Z</time>
        <cmt>Bareldonkdreef</cmt>
        <sym>Left_slight</sym>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="51.042177" lon="3.990587">
        <ele>4.8</ele>
        <time>2020-07-29T18:27:11Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="51.042175" lon="3.990478">
        <ele>4.8</ele>
        <time>2020-07-29T18:27:12Z</time>
    </trkpt>
```

Adding the turn info in trackpoints is discrete without interference in existing applications displays. As the existing applications simply ignore the 'extra' information added to trackpoints.

The original planner points (rtept) can still be recognised as "snapped to street" trkpt's with trkpt type Via or Shaping.
The most important element is the trkpt [EN]sym text which provides the correct Turn Command and Turn Icon.
The gpx [EN]sym method is so comparable with the well known tcx [EN]PointType mode in Garmin course files.
For the gpx track shown there has resolutely been chosen NOT to make use of the "associated" waypoints method.
In this way, a nice compact gpx waypoint list is not additionally polluted by these very many turnwaypoints.
The navigation app "scans" the trkpt's and thereby only promotes those with the correct standard[EN]sym text to be turnpoints.
The "Locus" standard [EN]sym text list contains considerably more instructions than only L/R/S as with tcx.

More info in the Locus map forum link: https://t.ly/XRai

Cruiser 100% supports gpx navigation track file transfers.
[Cruiser GPS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Cruiser)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/228244)